# Overlapping alpha transparency to create a density plot in matplolib

Tags: matplotlib, alpha

I want to create a plot using matplotlib. I basically draw many lines which overlap. I want to set alpha transparency on these lines such that if lines overlap the alpha values add up. My intention is to show the density of the overlapping lines with a more solid color, and lines that don't should be shown very lightly, this is the code I have but it is not giving the desired efect:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt = 0.00008
nstep = 3000
paths = 100

X = np.zeros((nstep,paths))
Y = np.zeros((nstep,paths))
gv1 = np.sqrt(dt)*np.random.randn(nstep,paths)
gv2 = np.sqrt(dt)*np.random.randn(nstep,paths)
for i in range(nstep-1):
        X[i+1] = X[i] + gv1[i]
        Y[i+1] = Y[i] + gv2[i]
plt.plot(X,Y,lw=1,alpha=0.05)
plt.show()
```

Comment: And what is wrong with this exactly? It's very pretty..

Comment: there in a 256 level granularity inherent in at least the agg derived backends (the color is internally represented by a 32bit field, 8 each for RGBA).